# Can't connect to mysql database from my ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, server

I'm such a noob with databases, so, I have my ubuntu server up and running, I have mySQL installed and I'm trying to create a simple database that will act as calendar, (when I will access to it through my android app, it will have to show me if at a specific day and hour, if I'm busy or not).
I have this my.cnf file:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[msqld]
bind-address = 192.168.1.8
port = 3306
```

When I try connecting to it using:

```
 mysql -h 192.168.1.8 -u root
```

from the terminal of my server it shows up this error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.8' (111)
```

I tried commenting bind-address line, and port line too. I tried binding 0.0.0.0, I tried adding user line and password line, nothing changed.
What am I doing wrong? and what should I add to my.cnf file?

Comment: did you check the firewall if port 3306 open is?

Comment: on the server you have to look for localhost or 127.0.0.1 since you are referencing to the very same machine.

Comment: on the remote you don't have to connect directly with the database. It will be the serverside language (PHP i.e.) to connect it (presumably via localhost on the same machine)

Comment: Yes, I have the 3306 port opened

Comment: `-h` is for the server you are trying to connect to. `bind-address` is for the IP(s) that you allow connections from. So are you on `192.168.1.8` or trying to connect to that. That is also is a LAN address are on the same network?

Comment: Oh, ok I thaught that bind-address was mysql server's ip. So, my server is on 192.168.1.8 and I'm connecting from the same machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow this : https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/

It could solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect from remote computer ?

- If yes (remote access), is 192.168.1.8 the good ip or try to remove the bind-address line
- If no (local access only), replace the IP by 127.0.0.1

And restard mysql daemon.

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: I'm not accessing from remote, but if I replace the IP with 127.0.0.1 I get this error
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

So I tried to add 
password = pwd
line to my.cnf file and it shows the same error but says (using password: YES)